# How to manage multiple certificate hashes in google-services.json?

Tags: android-keystore, google-play-services

In the google-services.json file, the certificate hash for the Android debug key store is added and committed into the source repo.

The certificate hash is different for each member in a dev team.
How can this be managed?
Is it possible to have multiple certificate hashes for a given oauth_client entry?

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Comment: Yes, one can add multiple entries in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oauth_client section in the google-services-json file accepts multiple entries. (It's an array)